# What are the various types of Banalingas that are present near Narmada river?

Tags: shiva-lingam, banalinga

Banalingas present near the holy Narmada river have various kinds of colours and design on them. Some are red , some have a black dot, some are bi coloured in red and white and various other colours. I have heard from sources like YouTube that , if the Banalinga comprises more red colour then it has the aggressive element of shiva in it. If it is bicoloured then it is Ardhanareeswarar banalinga, if black coloured then kalabhairava linga , so on and so forth. Can anyone share all the classifications of banalinga? Thank you.

Comment: I hope you check the answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58269/24460

Answer (score 1):

[Śālagrāmakośa (vol. 2) by S.K. Ramachandra Rao](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.162164/page/n135/mode/2up?view=theater) has a section devoted the discussion of bāṇaliṅgas and their various types, as per śāstras. I would be covering that in this answer. The citations provided by Rao, are difficult to find in the named śāstras, due to no numbering provided by him. But many quoted ślokas from Hemādri's Lakṣaṇakāṇḍa and Vīramitrodaya are available as quotations in Śabdakalpadruma.

According to Siddhāntaśekhara, the bāṇaliṅgas available in Narmadā river, are said to have been pūjita already by the devatās (especially by lokapālas), and these bāṇaliṅgas are also said to contain the marks of their pūjana.
The ones listed by Rao, are presented in a tabular form -

| Devatā who did pūjana | Marks on Bāṇaliṅga |
| --- | --- |
| Viṣṇu | śaṅkha on top (śaṅkābha-mastaka) |
| Brahmā | padma |
| Indra | chatra |
| Agni | two-heads (śiro-yugma) |
| Yama | three pādas |
| Īśāna | gadā |
| Varuṇa | kalaśa |
| Vāyu | dhvaja |

Mitramiśra's [Vīramitrodaya Lakṣaṇaprakāśa (pg. 594-596)](https://archive.org/details/ViraMitrodayaLakshanPrakashVol51987ReprintChowkhambaSanskritSeries/page/n599/mode/2up?view=theater), quotes Kālottara, which mentions the bāṇaliṅgas being distinguished by the marks of the devatās who did their pūjana. The śāstra enumerates 9 varieties of bāṇaliṅgas, which are as follows- Aindra, Āgneya, Yāmya, Naiṛṛti, Vāruṇa, Vāyāvya, Kaubera, Raudra, & Vaiṣṇava. The former eight correspond to the aṣṭadikpālas (Indra, Agni, Yama, Nirṛti, Varuṇa, Vāyu, Kubera, Rudra) & the latter to Viṣṇu. The pūjana of Aindraliṅga fulfills all the kāmanās and bestow sovereignity upon the sādhaka. Āgneyaliṅga is warm to touch, and bears the mark of śakti. Yāmyaliṅga bears the mark of daṇḍa or rasanā. Nairṛtiliṅga looks like a khaḍga, bears a stain on its body and bestows the benefits of jñāna and yoga. But the pūjana of Naiṛrtiliṅga shouldn't be done by a gṛhastha, lest it brings duḥkha, due to it having a rākṣasa svabhāva. Vāruṇaliṅga is round in shape and is distinguished by the mark of pāśa. Its pūjana secures prosperity. Vāyāvyaliṅga is kṛṣṇa in color, or dhūmra (ashy-grey); it has appearance of a dhvaja, or it bears the mark of dhvaja on its head. Kauberaliṅga is in the form of gadā or tūṇa, and may have a hair-like line in the centre. Raudraliṅga is lustrous like a block of ice, bears the marks of asthi or śūla. Vaiṣṇavaliṅga is distinguished by marks of śaṅka, cakra, padma, gadā, śrīvatsa & kaustubha, or pāda of Viṣṇu.

Hemādri in Lakṣaṇakāṇḍa, provides another classification of bāṇaliṅgas -

(i) **svayambhuliṅga** is madhupiṅgalavarṇam, bears the kṛṣṇa coil mark; it's adored by all yogic adepts. 
(ii) **mṛtyuñjayaliṅga** is multi-coloured, has the marks of jaṭā & śūla; its pūjana is done by suras & asuras. 
(iii) **nīlakaṇṭhaliṅga** is elongated in shape, has śubhravarṇa, with a kṛṣṇa dot in it. 
(iv) **trilocanliṅga** is śuklavarṇam, has three eye-like marks in it; there are also white lines resembling hairs in the body; the pūjā of this liṅga eliminates all pāpas. 
(v) **kālāgnirudraliṅga** is kṛṣṇavarṇam, stout in shape, brilliant in aspect; bears the marks of jaṭājūṭa ; it's pūjita by all beings. 
(vi) **tripurāriliṅga** is madhupiṅgalavarṇam, with a white line resembling the yajñopavīta ; there's a mark resembling crescent moon on the top, and at the bottom padma-like mark, white in colour, can be seen, there are also lines signifying one of the astras. 
(vii) **īśānaliṅga** is śubhravarṇam, with a piṅgalavarṇa jaṭā mark; there's a mark of a mālā of severed heads & triśūla. 
(viii) **ardhanārīśvaraliṅga** is distinguished by half of it being śukla and the other half being rakta in varṇam ; there's also mark of triśūla & ḍamaru. 
(ix) **mahākālaliṅga** is bright and corpulent in shape, elongated, and slightly red-hued ; it's bright and attractive, and its pūjana helps in the fulfilment of all the four puruṣārthas (dharma, kāma, artha and mokṣa).

Besides the above varieties, other śāstras such as Kālottara mention three other types of bāṇaliṅgas, which are daiva, gola and ārṣa. Daiva-bāṇaliṅga is very uneven on the surface, with scratches and holes, depressions and mounds, it's longish in shape and bears the marks of śūla, ṭaṅka and crescent moon. Gola-bāṅaliṅga resembles a small kūṣmāṇḍa or a crow's egg in shape. Ārṣa-bāṇaliṅga is like a rose-apple in shape, and bears the mark of brahmasūtra. It's fatter at the base than the rest of the body. Some liṅgas of this type are stout in the middle, and not so at the bottom or on the top, and these are the best among the liṅgas of this type.